# How to import a file from the same directory in python?

Tags: python, import

I have the following directory structure in python.

```
├── mel2samp.py
├── tacotron2
│   ├── layers.py
```

In mel2samp.py I want to import  `TacotronSTFT` from tacatron2.layers using these lines of code

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'tacotron2')
from tacotron2.layers import TacotronSTFT
```

But it throws an error 
`ImportError: No module named tacotron2.layers`.

Comment: Add a `__init__.py` file to the tacotron2 folder

Comment: @Karl wouldn't that make just the folder importable in a way like `import tacotron2.layers` instead? He can still use it's own way with `sys.path`

Comment: adding __init__.py solves it.thanks

Comment: By adding `__init__.py` python recongnises the tacotron2 folder as a module. Otherwise you are going to have to extend sys.path for every single module you want to import

Comment: Strange. I was unable to reproduce this problem. It ran without even an init fn.

Comment: @Karl Thanks that was indeed needed as an empty file!

Comment: @J...S Maybe it is the problem of editor I am using it is vscode. Mostly it complains about such issues.

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'tacotron2')
from tacotron2.layers import TacotronSTFT
# Use TacotronSTFT
```

But it is recommended to make tacotron2 as a package by adding init.py

Then you can use it as

`from tacotron2.layers import TacotronSTFT
 #Use TacotronSTFT`

Answer (score 1):

Also need an empty `__init__.py` file in `tacotron2` folder. After that you can do:

```
import sys
from tacotron2.layers import TacotronSTFT
```

Comment: it throws an error `ImportError: No module named layers`

Comment: I followed @Karl suggestion for the empty file

Comment: You don't need `sys.path.insert(0, '/tacotron2')` here. After adding `__init__` you can simply write `from tacotron2.layers import TacotronSTFT`

Answer (score 1):

You can make your folder a package by adding `__init__.py`
You can read more about it [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages)

> The `__init__.py` files are required to make Python treat the directories as containing packages; this is done to prevent directories with a common name, such as `string`, from unintentionally hiding valid modules that occur later (deeper) on the module search path. In the simplest case, `__init__.py` can just be an empty file, but it can also execute initialization code for the package or set the `__all__` variable, described later.